# How to automatically scroll vertical text?

Tags: unity, gui

I've a GUI, and a panel with a Text control.

I simply want to do an automatic vertical scroll effect (circular).

Problems I've to solve: 
- How to identify if text on my textbox is "too much" and overflow vertical

- How to move Text and not textbox transform Y

Can you help me find the correct solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved:

1. I put my text control inside a Panel
2. I add a Rect Mask 2d to my panel
3. I wrote this simple script to attach to Text control:

   ```
   [SerializeField] float              SecondsAfterStartAutoscroll;
   [SerializeField] float              ScrollSpeed;

   bool isScrolling = false;
   RectTransform rectTransf;

   void Start()
   {

       rectTransf = GetComponent<RectTransform>();        
       Invoke("EnableScroll", SecondsAfterStartAutoscroll);  
   }


   void EnableScroll()
   {
       isScrolling = true;
   }

   void Update()
   {
       if(isScrolling)
       {
           rectTransf.Translate(new Vector3(0, 1, 0) * Time.deltaTime * ScrollSpeed);
       }
   }
   ```

What I haven't solved yet: loop circular scroll... text didn't restart after last 'sentences' finish ..

[image]